# Scipy Optimal parameters not found: Number of calls to function has reached maxfev = 800

Tags: python-2.7, scipy, curve-fitting, non-linear-regression

Trying for the logarithmic fit on the dataset using the codes posted. I keep getting `Optimal parameters not found: Number of calls to function has reached maxfev = 800`. Can you help me
1. Resolve the error
2. If the equation I'm using is a good one for the current dataset
3. Suggest any alternative method?

```
Dataset  
      Years        Values
    0    2000      23.0
    1    2001      27.5
    2    2002      46.0
    3    2003      56.0
    4    2004      64.8
    5    2005      71.2
    6    2006      80.2
    7    2007      98.0
    8    2008     113.0
    9    2009     155.8
    10   2010     414.0
    11   2011    2297.8
    12   2012    3628.4
    13   2013   16187.8
    14   2014   25197.8
    15   2015   42987.8
    16   2016   77555.5
    17   2017  130631.9

X = np.array(df.Years, dtype = float)
y = np.array(df.Values, dtype = float)
def func(x, a, b, c):
    return a * np.exp(b * x) + c
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, X, y)
plt.plot(X, y, 'ro', label="Original data")
plt.plot(X, func(X, *popt), label="Fitted Curve")
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

Comment: I found that the data is better fitted when a "shift" is added inside 
the exponential term. For example, when I fit the equation "y = a * 
exp(bx + c) + Offset" ("c" is the shift) with the fitted parameters a =  
1.4480580672721226E+03,  b =  5.4832701921529625E-01, c = 
-1.1014608660085264E+03 and Offset = -7.6418038547928484E+02 I get a 
fairly good fit with R-squared = 0.998

Comment: @JamesPhillips You can simplify that to `y = exp(bx + c) + Offset`.  With four parameters, the model has a redundant parameter.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser - Excellent insight. Yes, the fit is equally good with the same R-squared = 0.998 and updated parameters b =  5.4832703431291518E-01, c = -1.0941829177914260E+03, and Offset = -7.6418016326998327E+02